# Equivalent VBA code to double click a cell and press enter

Tags: vba

I wanted to use VBA to automate the process of double clicking a specific cell in the worksheet and then perform the pressing "Enter" action.

The reason that I do this is that the formula in cell A1 is a special formula in add-ins.
I used a loop to fill in A1 the special formula containing different symbol in  sheet to extract information about the Symbol. Then, I will filter the data to get today's information and corresponding Tic.

The information will not show if I use the .calculate method in VBA. I must manually double click it and press enter.

Can anyone please help about this? Thank you in advance!

```
Sub getTIC()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim Row_max As Integer
    Dim Row_maxTIC As Integer
    Dim CreationDate_Col As Integer
    Dim TIC_Col As Integer
    Dim Symbol As String
    Dim CreationDate As String
    Dim TIC As String
    
    With Worksheets("General")
    Row_max = .Range("B63655").End(xlUp).Row
    
        For i = 3 To Row_max
            'Loop through list of Symbols
            .Range("C1") = .Range("B" & i)
            Symbol = .Range("C1").Value
            
            'Refresh Optrad formula to get Symbol information 
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("InstrTIC").Calculate
            
            'Locate Instr TIC# (tradableinfoID) column number
            p = 1
            Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InstrTIC").Cells(1, p) = "tradableInfoID"
            p = p + 1
            Loop
            TIC_Col = p
            
            'Locate Creation date column number
            p = 1
            Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InstrTIC").Cells(1, p) = "creationDate"
            p = p + 1
            Loop
            CreationDate_Col = p
            
            'Filter today's TIC# to <General> sheet
            Row_maxTIC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("InstrTIC").Range("A63655").End(xlUp).Row
            For j = 2 To Row_maxTIC
                CreationDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("InstrTIC").Cells(j, CreationDate_Col).Value
                TIC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("InstrTIC").Cells(j, TIC_Col).Value

                If CDate(Val(Left(CreationDate, 5))) = Date Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("General").Range("A" & i) = TIC
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks a x, y question. I mean, you ask about something and need something else... Please, edit your question and show us the code you use **to need the mentioned double click** for updating the cell value.

Comment: Definitely sounds like an [X,Y Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Maybe the add-in formula isn't set to [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Volatile).  Saying that you could select cell A1 and use `Application.SendKeys ("{F2}~")`

Comment: Is calculation set on `Automatic`? If you press `F9` instead of editing followed by `Enter`, is the formula calculated?

Comment: @FaneDuru, calculation is set on Manual. If I press F9, the formula in Cell A1 will not be calculated. It does not work even if I select A1 and press enter, it only works if I double click and press enter.

Comment: Please, share the function code and explain the context of using it.

Comment: I cannot see any function in your code, I do not see in your code any code line writing a formula in "A1". What does "the formula in cell A1 is a special formula in add-ins" mean? Is it written somewhere in the code you show and I missed? Is it a result of a UDF and it has been placed in "A1" manually, or in another (secret) procedure? I still cannot understand what problem you have.

Comment: @FaneDuru. Yes, there is a formula placed in A1. Sorry, I need to hide part of the formula, "=Obj_GetField("gr://****/****/fullQuery?symbol="&General!C1,"")"

Comment: I am afraid that what you posted is not relevant... I asked about the function which brings data in A1... So, the necessary (required) code to be evaluated is the one of `Obj_GetField` function. It, theoretically, should not contain confidential data, the necessary url being supplied as an argument. Does the respective function use a query? How does it extract the necessary data from the respective url?

Comment: hi @FaneDuru, yes, it it an addin function, it's not from Excel. It extract data from company's system. The problem is that I need to double click the cell and press enter after I filled in the formula. The .Calculate method using VBA will not do the same thing. So I am wondering how can I use VBA to perform the same action of double clicking and the press enter on a cell, hope this clarifies my question, thank you.

Comment: No, it does not... I was asking about that function, in order to see if a query is involved. In such a case refeshing that query may solve the problem.

Comment: And that add-in must be **an Excel add-in**, not something outside Excel! So, is it a COM Add-in, or a VBA add-in? At least, do you know its name?

Comment: =Obj_GetField("gr://apac/instrument/fullQuery?symbol="&General!C1,""), I don't know how the function works. I only know that it will extract information for specified symbol.

Comment: @FaneDuru
I don't know whether it's a COM add-in or VBA add-in. Each time I use the template, I will need to go to Add-in, and click on this add-in to start it, so the functions can work.

Comment: What do you mean by "need to go to Add-in, and click on this add-in to start it"? Where do you go? What name does the respective add-in have? In order to use a formula existing in an add-in, a reference to the respective one must exist in the 'template' you are talking about. What name has the add-in you are talking about? Extension included, please... Try going `File - Options - Add-ins`. Do you see its name in the add-ins list shown in the right pane? If it looks complicated, try the next code line `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`, instead of invoking `Calculate`...